# Google Cloud PubSub giving - A pull requests for subscription went to a server that is temporarily overloaded. Please try the request again

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-pubsub, gcloud-node

I have 16 workers subscribed to a topic and they are using pull mechanism to retrieve the messages from the queue.
I very frequently get `Error: A pull requests for subscription '/subscriptions/quizizz-org/socket-worker' went to a server that is temporarily overloaded. Please try the request again.` as reply.

My first guess was that may be because of some quota limit, but I could not find any quota limit for pull requests send to a subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that says the requests "went to a server that is temporarily overloaded" is not a message that indicates exceeding any quota limits. In this case, the issue is an isolated problem for which a fix should be rolled out by end of day 2/3/2017.